# Left Div Fixed, Multiple Right Divs Scrollable

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to have a static left div and have the right divs be scrollable. I'd like to be flexible so I set widths and heights to percentage basis.

Currently, when I scroll the left div scrolls with the right div, so when I reach the second right div in the stack, there is not left div associated to it.

I'd like for the left div to always remain and only the right divs to scroll.

HTML:

```
<div class= "div-left div-left-small">
</div>
<div class= "div-right-1 div-right-1-small">
</div>
<div class= "div-right-2 div-right-2-small">
</div>
<div class="div-right-3 div-right-3-small">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html{
height:100%;
width:100%;
margin: 0px;
}

body{
height:100%;
width: 100%;
margin: 0px;
}

.div-left{
    background-color: darkblue;
    height: 100%;
    width:50%;
    margin: 0px;
    float: left;
    position: static;
}

.div-right-1{
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0px;
    float: right;
} 

.div-right-2{
    background-color: aqua;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    margin:0px;
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to set position: fixed for left div. Check code below.

```css
html{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin: 0px;
}

body{
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
}

.div-left{
    background-color: darkblue;
    height: 100%;
    width:50%;
    margin: 0px;
    float: left;
    position: fixed;
}

#clear {
    clear: both;
}

.div-right-1{
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0px;
    float: right;
} 

.div-right-2{
    background-color: aqua;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    margin:0px;
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class= "div-left div-left-small">
</div>
<div class= "div-right-1 div-right-1-small">
</div>
<div id="clear"></div>
<div class= "div-right-2 div-right-2-small">
</div>
<div class="div-right-3 div-right-3-small">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Nimish, your method worked best for what I was trying to accomplish

Answer (score 1):

you need the first in fixed position and the rest be margin-left at 50% ... if i understood:

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

.div-left {
  background-color: darkblue;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0px;
  position: fixed;
}

[class^="div-right"] {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 50%;
}

.div-right-2 {
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-left div-left-small">
</div>
<div class="div-right-1 div-right-1-small">
</div>
<div class="div-right-2 div-right-2-small">
</div>
<div class="div-right-3 div-right-3-small">
</div>
```